# Customize output using ods latex tagset

Tags: sas

My question is twofold 
1) Is there a way to output all the files in one latex file directly? 
2) Can I fully customize the caption?

1)
I have a series of tables to ouput in one latex file. Actually each tables are printed in a different file. Is there a way to output all the files in one latex file directly?

2) I have customized the tablesonlylatex tagset to obtain the display I wanted except that I didn't managed to put the table caption. I basically would like this latex format (the basic one).

```
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\begin{center}
```

**    **\caption{PUT \sassystemtitle here}**

```
\begin{tabular}{lrr}\hline
   Region &    Variable A &    Variable B\\
   Africa &    27.16\% &    24.72\%\\
   East Asia and the Pacific &    25.24\% &    16.10\%\\
   Eastern Europe and Central Asia &    8.75\% &    13.71\%\\
   Latin America and The Caribbean &    33.15\% &    36.66\%\\
   Middle East and North Africa &    3.39\% &    6.19\%\\
   South Asia &    2.32\% &    2.62\%\\
\hline
\end{center}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Here is my modified tablesonlylatex tagsets.

```
define tagset tagsets.tablesonlylatex; parent=tagsets.simplelatex;
        define event verbatim_text;end;
        define event table_head;end;
                define event table;
           start:
               put '\begin{table}' CR '\begin{center}' CR;
           finish:
               put '\hline' CR'\end{center}' CR'\end{tabular}' CR '\end{table}';
               put CR;
        end;
        define event colspec_entry;
            put just '' / if !cmp(just, 'd');
            put 'c' / if cmp(just, 'd');
        end;
        define event colspecs;
            start:
                put CR'\begin{tabular}{';
            finish:
                put '}\hline' CR ;
        end;

        define event row;
            finish:
                put '\\' CR;
        end;
        define event data;
            start:
                put VALUE /if cmp($sascaption, 'true');
                break /if cmp($sascaption, 'true');
                put ' & ' / if !cmp(COLSTART, '1') ;

                /* Print cell formatting including class name and alignment. */
                put '   ';
                unset $colspan;
                set $colspan colspan;
                put '\multicolumn{' / if exists($colspan);
                put colspan  / if exists($colspan);
                put '}'      / if exists($colspan);
                put '{'     / if exists($colspan);
                put just     / if exists($colspan);
                put '}'     / if exists($colspan);
                put '{'      / if exists($colspan);
/*

*/
                /*put strip(VALUE);*/
                put tranwrd(VALUE, '-', '$-$') / if contains(HTMLCLASS, 'Data');
                put VALUE / if ! contains(HTMLCLASS, 'Data');

            finish:
                break /if cmp($sascaption, 'true');
                put '}'      / if exists($colspan);
        end;
        define event byline; end;
        define event proc_title; end;
        define event note; end;
        define event Error; end;
        define event Warn; end;
        define event Fatal; end;
        define event system_footer; end;
        define event leaf; end;
        define event proc_branch; end;
        define event branch; end;
        define event pagebreak; end;
        define event system_title;end;
    end;
```

Comment: Which version of SAS are you using? You could use `ODS LATEX` as your output destination and include multiple outputs using `ODS REGION`. If I recall, these features are available in v9.3+.

Comment: Hello I'm using the 9.3 version